# How can i use ofstream in class that is wrapped with Boost.Python to Python?

Tags: python, c++, file-io, iostream, boost-python

**I changed the code one month ago and im stucking at the same error which i described below. I dont find a pretty simple example how to expose an fstream object with Boost.Python to Python to solve my explained problem**

In short words i just want to expose a Class that contains an I/O object with functions write / open / close. In Pyton i want to do these steps:

1. open File1
2. open File2
3. open File3
4. write to File1
5. write to File2
6. write to File3
7. close files

**C/C++ Code**

```
////// I N C L U D E S //////
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
////////////////////////////


using namespace std;

struct BoostXML_IO
{
    ofstream File;

    void writeFile(const string& strToWrite)
    {
        this->File.write(strToWrite.data(), strToWrite.size());
    }

    void openFile(const string& path)
    {
        this->File.open(path, ios::app);
    }

    void closeFile()
    {
        this->File.close();
    }

};


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(BoostXML_IO)
{
    using namespace boost::python;  
    class_<BoostXML_IO, boost::noncopyable>("BoostXML_IO")
      .def("writeFile", &BoostXML_IO::writeFile)
      .def("openFile", &BoostXML_IO::openFile)
      .def("closeFile", &BoostXML_IO::closeFile)
    ;
}
```

This code always compiles without an error but finally in Python i always get the following error when i try to invoke one of the functions in the prompt line.

**ERROR code**

```
>>> import BoostXML_IO
>>> File1 = BoostXML_IO
>>> File = BoostXML_IO.BoostXML_IO.openFileFailed to format the args
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\app\tools\Python25\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\idle\CallTips.py", line 130, in get_arg_text
    argText = inspect.formatargspec(*arg_getter(fob))
  File "C:\app\tools\Python25\Lib\inspect.py", line 743, in getargspec
    raise TypeError('arg is not a Python function')
TypeError: arg is not a Python function
(
```

Thank you a lot in advance !

Comment: You must have some kind of reason to believe there is a error. It would be wonderful if you would share what you have tried, and what went wrong. Does it compile? if not, what are the compiler errors?

Comment: @M4rtini sorry i forgot to add my error code of the command prompt

Comment: Mbeyond the compiler problems, you never declare ``myFile`` at the class level (only as a local in your open method), yet use it in every class method. That isn't going to work. You also declare ``strToWrite`` as a ``const char``, but then in your write method you make it an input parameter and declare it as ``const char *``. Beyond this type conflict, why not just make it a ``string``?

Comment: Please post the other error messages as well, specifically the line with information about which line in your code the error is originating from. Btw: You don't need the `this->` in front of `myFile`.

Comment: This is probably because the implicitly generated copy constructor of your struct tries to copy the `myFile` member. Copying a stream is not allowed, so compilation fails. Disable the copy constructor in your struct by adding `private: BoostXML_IO(const BoostXML_IO&);`

Comment: @jasal that doesn't worked for me

Comment: Where is the parameter in your `openFile` call?

Comment: @jasal i can't enter a parameter, because i got the error code after i entered a "("..

Answer (score 1):

Your compile errors have nothing to do with Boost.Python. Start by including `<string>` and `<ofstream>` and add a `using namespace std;`. That should fix most of the errors you're getting. Then fix your struct declaration like so:

```
struct BoostXML_IO
{    
  void openFile(const string& path)
  {
    myfile.open(path);
  }
  void closeFile()
  {
    myfile.close();
  }
  void WriteToFile(const char* strToWrite)
  {
    myfile.write(strToWrite, strlen(strToWrite));
  }

private:
  ofstream myFile;
};
```

I also don't see a need for setting a readwrite reference to the `strToWrite` and `path` members when you pass them as parameters in `openFile` and `WriteToFile`.

---

**EDIT** What about this:

```
struct BoostXML_IO
{
    BoostXML_IO()
    {}

    void writeFile(const string& strToWrite)
    {
        File.write(strToWrite.data(), strToWrite.size());
    }

    void openFile(const string& path)
    {
        File.open(path, ios::out);
    }

    void closeFile()
    {
        File.close();
    }

private:
    BoostXML_IO(const BoostXML_IO&);
    BoostXML_IO& operator=(const BoostXML_IO&);

    ofstream File;
};


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(BoostXML_IO)
{
    using namespace boost::python;  
    class_<BoostXML_IO>("BoostXML_IO", init<>())
      .def("writeFile", &BoostXML_IO::writeFile)
      .def("openFile", &BoostXML_IO::openFile)
      .def("closeFile", &BoostXML_IO::closeFile)
    ;
}
```

I have no idea why you'd want to expose an `ofstream` to the python API. Same for the `pathToFile` variable which is kind of useless when specifying the file path in `openFile`. But I think I mentioned that already.

Comment: i changed my code, but now i have a problem with boost.python. Because boost.python can't access my private declared class members. Can you give ma a simple example for my spefici I/O handling ?

Comment: i want to expose this because its much faster than equivalent python functions for writing one line to a file. I did some runtime measurements and ofstream.write() won the race. I also did a runtime measurement when i just exposed the write function to the python API. But as i mentionend i want 1 object for 1 file i'm writing to, because i have to access many times to these 3 files at my programm.

Comment: My question was why you would want to expose the `File` variable in your struct directly when you already have functions which duplicate the `ofstream` interface.

Comment: i don't know how its possible to access the files without ofstream File variable for writing to the file ? If you have any other solutions that contain my desired functionalities i would be very happy!

Comment: your solution don't works. Do you have another solution how i can expose a C++ class with a fstream member with boost.python?

Comment: No I don't have another solution because you don't even bother to tell us why the last one didn't work.

Comment: same problem with accessing private members.
i have now a code that i can compile, but i have another problems now in python

Comment: finally you dont answer to my last change. I changed the question and described my problem above.

Comment: Where are the functions arguments to openFile in your call?

Comment: i got the error message when i try to enter "(", furthermore i cant enter the function arguments ? I thought the reason is that i block to copy the constructor of the ofstream object ?

Comment: You have not created an instance of BoostXML_IO in your python session. What happens when you do `file = BoostXML_IO()` and then `file.openFile("some/path")`?

Comment: I created an instance of BoostXML_IO. Afterwards when i want to invoke the function it will raise an Python Interpreter error (TypeError: arg is not a Python function).